# Dynamic queries in Hibernate keeps in memory

Tags: hibernate, memory-management, memory-leaks

I use Hibernate in my app and I have this question:

Queries are automatically generated by Hibernate, I use this code to retrieve objects from DB:

```
Object result = session.get(clazz, id);
```

where *id* is a *Serializable* object.

My app runs for a long time in batch execution. I take an .hprof file to study memory and I have this situation: lots and lots of String queries generated by Hibernate. With Eclipse Memory Analyzer (MAT), I see this:

[image]

So lots of *select...* like this are retained in memory and I don't know how to *free* or *dispose* them. My app runs out of memory after some time.

Any suggestion would be very helpful. Thanks in advance

Comment: can you turn Hibernate debugging on so we have an idea what queries are being generated?